# Algorithm needed to generate combinations of shifted characters

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I know the exact sequence and length of my TrueCrypt partition's password, but I can't recall which characters are up-shifted via the Shift key.  I wrote a perl script (like CrackTC) that simply tries all passwords from a file but I'm seeking an algorithm to generate the password file quickly.  The password is 42 characters so any advice will be helpful.

I realized that I would only have shifted numbers and punctuation, so only 17 of the characters need to be changed.

Note this is not a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick python script:

```
def isShiftable(c):
    return not c in "123456789"

def generate(str, i=0):
    if len(str) <= i:
        print "".join(str)
    else:
        if isShiftable(str[i]):
            str[i]=str[i].upper()
            generate(str, i+1)
            str[i]=str[i].lower()
            generate(str, i+1)
        else:
            generate(str, i+1)

generate(list("testit123"))
```

I'm sure it can be cleaned up, and made less bad, but it should suffice.

For 17 shiftable characters, there should be 131072 possibilities. Also, you will need to define your own 'upper'/'lower' function for shifting punctuation.

Comment: I like it - thank you.  This combined with a binary counting (a la hightechrider and slartibartfast's answers) inspired me.  I created 2 tables, 1 fixed and 1 shifted characters. I was able to reduce the number of shifted characters because of patterns I typically use when creating long passwords.  It's still running, hope it works.

Comment: Update: After some 30 hrs of generating the password list, the brute-force test script found the password at around the 2750 mark -- about 11 minutes.

Comment: @zhaopian now that is entertaining :) Congrats on recovering the password.

Answer (score 4):

Since each character can be upper or lower that's equivalent to one bit.  You have 42 bits.  Count in binary and set the character to upper or lower case according to the pattern of the binary bits.  2 to the power 42 is a very large number!!  Too large to find by brute force!  Good luck!

Comment: It turns out that a 42 character password consisting of only upper- and lower-case `A` would be almost twice as strong as an 8-character alphanumeric password!  (2^42 ~ 2 * (36^8))

Comment: Yikes - that's not do-able! Now you've got me thinking (which I should have done earlier). I can reduce the work because I would have shifted only 17 of the characters (numbers and punctuation), does that make it 2^17?  I've updated my question.

Comment: Yup, that's somewhat more reasonable, might be feasible now depending on how long each check takes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have to try all combinations, and that each password attempt is separated by a single character, the password file for all possible capitalizations of a 42 character password would be 189 terabytes in length.  You probably don't want to work directly from a file.

The algorithm I would choose is a binary counting algorithm, but instead of toggling a single bit, toggle the capitalization of a single character.  I would strongly suggest narrowing the pool with rules of thumb that you remember (like: Definitely had more than 5 uppercase, and fewer than 40 uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but it might reduce your search space:

- Minimum and maximum of uppercase (could be 4 and 10)
- Minimum and maximum sequence of uppercase (could as well be 1 and 1)
- Minimum and maximum sequence of lowercase (could be 2 and 15)
- Some combinations are more probable than the others, and should be checked first. For instance group combinations by maximum sequence of uppercase and first check those with minimal such value.

Answer (score 1):

42 letter password, and you know the letters, then there are 2^41 (that is: `2 199 023 255 552`) unique combinations. If you could check 10m of them in 1 second, then you could brute force it - and it would take at least: 61 hours  5 minutes  2 seconds.

You most likely wont have to do that much work. Let x be the number of uppercase letters:

- If you had `7 > x` uppercase letters: (42!)/(6! 36!)+(42!)/(5! 37!)+(42!)/(4! 38!)+(42!)/(3! 39!)+(42!)/(2! 40!)+(42!)/(1! 41!) = `6 220 767` combinations.
- If you had `6 < x < 9` uppercase letters: (42!)/(8! 34!)+(42!)/(7! 35!) = `145 008 513` combinations.

If you can automate checking process and check `2000` elements in a second, then on **worst case**:

- If you had `7 > x` uppercase letters, it would take: 51.84 minutes
- If you had `6 < x < 9` uppercase letters, it would take: 20.14 hours

Most likely you need some special case permutation algorithm to efficiently find the unique elements. This is quite complex problem, but I don't see any other way, as iterating over 2^41 elements is nuts.

Comment: I agree - it's nuts to do it without some sort of reduction.  As you pointed out, brute force is ok if I could check 10m/sec, but it's more like 10/sec (OW!).  However, once I have the password generator, I could run it on multiple machines.  Thanks.